# Best practice to design a microservice system with both staff and customer login

Tags: .net, microservices, identityserver4, abp

We have a .net microservice erp system powered by abp framework. We implement user login using identity server 4 and asp.net identity. However, now we have to add customer feature where customers of the enterprise could log on to a mobile app and look up some data from some services. Previously, all users were staffs of the company. We are struggling on the way of adding customer login to the system. Option 1 could be add a usertype column to current database but this way we have to change a lot of apis to filter user types. Option 2 I could think of is add another identity server 4 and asp.net identity project and database to serve the customer only. And use client credential to access the erp’s microservices when needed.

Comment: is this a use case for `Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy`?

Comment: Yes, I am using Multitenancy. But we need to expose some infos to the customers of the tenant.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is not an good design. Better option is use Role Based Security in your application. Identity Server provide this option. Yeah, this solution will add overhead in your code initially but that will be beneficial in long run.

Comment: What is a better design to distinguish between customer and employee users. For circumstances such as get list of all employees or list of all customers. Is it practical to distinguish them by roles or claims?

Comment: As you are using microservice architecture style so there should be different service to manage customer data and different service managing employee data.

Comment: Don't use role or claims for getting list or other details.